# how to reassign the function argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

### The challenge & explanation.

I want to reassign a global variable when it's passed to a function as an argument but here is the catch I don't want to reference it directly inside of the function so here is the result I want to occur.

```
let number = 5;

function changesVariable() {
  number = 3;
}
changesVariable();
console.log(number); // 3
```

but I don't want to directly add "number" inside of the function I want a behavior like below I want to pass "number" as an argument and then the function reassigns it by that.

```
let number = 5;

function changesVariable(n) {
  n = 3;
}
changesVariable(number);
console.log(number); // here it returns 5 but would like to see 3
```

BTW I know the above code is wrong it's here only to explain the concept.

### How I tried to solve it

so below are some examples that how I approach it. but their arent the answer.

```
function changesVariable(n) {
  arguments[0] = 3;
}
changesVariable(number);
console.log(number); // still 5
```

we can do something like:

```
function changesVariable(n) {
  return (arguments[0] = 3);
}
number = changesVariable();
console.log(number);
```

but I am seeking an answer with these conditions:

1. reassign the "number" by passing it to function as an argument.
2. I don't want to use "number" variable directly inside the function.

### If all the text above didn't help

I want to create a Utils function that you can pass different global variables to it and it will reassign them that's why I have this approach I want the function to be reusable like:

```
changesVariable(number1);
changesVariable(number2);
changesVariable(number3);
changesVariable(number4);
```

Comment: JavaScript is a pass-by-value language, i.e. functions are being passed a *copy* of the value (not to be confused with object references). I.e. what you want isn't possible, at least not exactly like that...

Comment: I want to create a function that's reusable and you can use it to change multiple global variables.

Comment: @alirezahekmati But _why_ do you want that? Why do they need to be global variables? Remember you'd have no issue if these were in a single object: `{"number1": 1, ...}`.

Comment: @AKX yes that works as well basically a variable that is a reference type.sorry  for late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `let` binding in your example.

There is no accessible namespace for a `let` (or `const`, but that's beside the point here since you're talking about writing things) bound variable, so in short, **what you're asking for is impossible** in JavaScript.

If you had a `var` in global scope, you could access it via [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) by name:

```
> var foo = 8;
> globalThis.foo
8
> globalThis.foo = 9
9
> foo
9
```

However, it sounds like you don't really even need global variables here; why not just put these variables in an object of your own?

```
> const things = {foo: 8};
> function modify(name, value) { things[name] = value; }
> modify("foo", 9)
> things
{ foo: 9 }
```

(And yes, you can use `modify` with `globalThis` too...)

Comment: Thank you I am not going to take more time from you more than this. I have found the answer I have to use the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think with primitive it's not possible cause it's not a reference data type.
Try to put it into an object like: {n: 5}, and pass it like this.

```
let number = {n:5};
function changesVariable(number) {
   number.n = 3;
}
changesVariable(number);
console.log(number.n);
```

This is going to work because it's not a primitive, but more like a reference type with a primitive in it. So the function parameter and the global variable will be pointing to the same memory address.
More info: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-reference-data-types-in-Java#:~:text=Reference%20datatypes%20in%20java%20are,an%20object%20of%20a%20class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-reference-data-types-in-Java#:%7E:text=Reference%20datatypes%20in%20java%20are,an%20object%20of%20a%20class).

Comment: aha got it so I have to use something that passed by reference. lets w8  for more answers.                                                       
 Thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a pass-by-value language, i.e. functions are being passed a copy of the value (not to be confused with object references). I.e. what you want isn't possible, at least not exactly like that...

> I want to create a Utils function that you can pass different global variables

How about that utils function accepts a callback which accepts the new value and can do whatever it wants with that?

```
function change(callback) {
  callback(3)
}

//...


change(newValue => {
  number1 = newValue;
  number2 = newValue;
})
```

If the function needs the current value of the/a variable you can pass that in too (but your requirements are not clear).

Comment: the example above won't help I am trying to reduce duplicate code. this way it's just as like if I use the variable directly inside the function. thanks for the contribution I think using objects is the way to go.

Comment: *"I am trying to reduce duplicate code"* If you literally just assign a new value to a variable then yes, that seems overkill. But so is replacing assignments with function calls. I think it would have been better if you had provided an excerpt of your actual code and asked a question about it than to abstract it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with eval(), just pass the name of the global var to the function:

```
let number = 5;

function changesVariable(arg) {
    let a = eval(`'(${arg}) = 3'`)
    a = a.replace('(','')
    a = a.replace(')','')
    console.log(a);
    eval(a)
}
changesVariable('number');
console.log(number);
```

But using eval() is not recommended...